# How do you reliably kill Shining Poms?

Tags: trails-in-the-sky-sc

Shining poms in the second game are worth a LOT of experience points.

[image: On the victory screen, characters are about to get ALL of the levels.]

However, it seems like Estelle's S-Craft are the only reliable way to take Shining poms down — Anelace's, Olivier's, etc. only barely scratch them (Olivier just dealt *40* damage on his 200 CP S-Craft with crits), while Agate's only gets them halfway through without turn bonuses. Estelle recently has only been gaining about 3-4 craft points per hit, when that is usually 10. Without someone like Kevin in your party distributing CP around, that won't work particularly well.

Is that it? Is Estelle the only way to take Shining Poms down before they flee? or are there other arts or craft that are also effective?